# Помогите расшифровать текст методом частотного анализа

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, шифрование, анализ-данных, статистика

Необходимо расшифровать текст методом частотного подбора. В нём может быть пропущена буква, знаков препинания нет, пробелы расставлены. Вот текст

```
ЩСЗ ЙАБПЫАИДЙАЮЮВЗ П ЮАИЧСБУЧС ЩАХБПДАБУЮВЗ НСИШХПЮВ ИГВЦШ 
ЮВЕГВБВ НГОДП П ГЙВЮШБВИУ ЙНАГАХ И ШЩСЩ ГВЦГАЦВЗ ЙСХШ РШБ 
ЩДСГВ ШИПБПБИЗ П ЦЙШЧ ИДВБ ЙОА З СРБЗЮШБВИУ ДАЩЮВЗ ИДАЮВ 
ИЧВБ ЕОИДГС ШХВБЗБВИУ ЦВ ЧСГВЕБАЩ ДЗЮШБИЗ НСЕБАИЧПЙВЛЭПЬ 
ИАГАЕГСЩ ИБАХ
```

Comment: эщькере айтануси махадоку пухивана жатсмицу дакивайфайя :)

Comment: подозреваю, что надо взять какую-то известную таблицу частот букв, потом разбить данный текст на буквы и пробовать заменять на основе значений полученных частот. Или каков там метод, если метод есть, то надо ему просто следовать, или что?

Comment: я составила таблицу с частотностью букв в зашифрованном тексте и сравнила с частотностью букв русского языка Символ Частота
В 8.98%
Б 7.76%
И 7.35%
А  6.94%
С 5.31%
Г  4.90%
Ш  4.49%
З 4.49%
П 4.49%
Ю 4.49%
Д 3.67%
Щ 3.27%
Й 3.27%
Ч 2.45%
Х 2.45%
У 2.04%
Ц 2.04%
Е 2.04%
Н 1.63%
О 1.22%
Р  0.82%
Ы 0.41%
Л 0.41%
Э 0.41%
Ь 0.41%
Выше мой текст

Comment: По заданию одна буква пропущена, а сопоставление по частотности результатов не дало.

Comment: Откуда вы взяли этот текст?

Comment: дали задание для курсовой работы

Comment: частоты изучать можно не только у букв, но например у предлогов и окончаний

Comment: начать можно с буквы "П". Это или "и", или "в" или "а" или "я". Других однобуквенных слов в русском языке, вроде бы, нет. То же самое с "З".

Comment: @Эникейщик, `авикосуя` - список однобуквенных слов. `А рыбу в рот и к нам. О ком и с кем и у кого я?`.

Answer (score 4):

Текст в редактор, слова на отдельные строки и попробую менять буквы. Чтобы различать, что уже поменяно, а что осталось, заглавные меняются на строчные.

С наскока не вышло. Тогда я набросал вычисление частот и попробовал менять буквы по частотам. Получилась чепуха. Фрагмент короткий, частоты отклоняются от таблицы, найденной в Сети. Не сработало.

Тогда я попробовал анализировать слова. Тут кое-что получилось. Сперва меня увлекла пара слов `ЩСЗ` и `ШЩСЩ`. Второе слово вообще замечательное. Я придумал что это `удод`. А первое тогда `до?`. Что `до?`? `дон`? `док`? Тупик.

Однобуквенные слова `П`, `И`, `З`. Каждое из них может быть одним из `авикосуя`. Вариантов много, очевидного выбора я не увидел. Опять тупик.

Следующее слово, которое привлекло моё внимание, - `ЙАБПЫАИДЙАЮЮВЗ`. Особенно `ЮЮВЗ`. Это может быть `нный`, `нное`, `нная`, `нные` и ещё сколько-то вариантов. Если к этому добавить слово `З`, то, кажется, есть фаворит, и он один: `нная`. Три буквы есть, и я более или менее в них уверен. Такой старт - отличный стимул.

```
ЩСя ЙАБПЫАИДЙАнная П нАИЧСБУЧС ЩАХБПДАБУная НСИШХПна ИГаЦШ наЕГаБа НГОДП П
ГЙанШБаИУ ЙНАГАХ И ШЩСЩ ГаЦГАЦая ЙСХШ РШБ ЩДСГа ШИПБПБИя П ЦЙШЧ ИДаБ ЙОА я
СРБянШБаИУ ДАЩная ИДАна ИЧаБ ЕОИДГС ШХаБяБаИУ Ца ЧСГаЕБАЩ ДянШБИя
НСЕБАИЧПЙаЛЭПЬ ИАГАЕГСЩ ИБАХ
```

Слово `Ца`. Первая буква может быть одна из `дзнт`. Выбрать однозначно трудно. Но тут я заметил слово `ГаЦГАЦая` и догадался, что если `Ц` это `з`, то слово дописывается до `разрезая`! Для других букв варианты не придумались, а этот обещает сразу три буквы. Заменяем их.

```
ЩСя ЙеБПЫеИДЙенная П неИЧСБУЧС ЩеХБПДеБУная НСИШХПна ИразШ наЕраБа НрОДП П
рЙанШБаИУ ЙНереХ И ШЩСЩ разрезая ЙСХШ РШБ ЩДСра ШИПБПБИя П зЙШЧ ИДаБ ЙОе я
СРБянШБаИУ ДеЩная ИДена ИЧаБ ЕОИДрС ШХаБяБаИУ за ЧСраЕБеЩ ДянШБИя
НСЕБеИЧПЙаЛЭПЬ ИереЕрСЩ ИБеХ
```

Теперь `ДеЩная` и `ИДена`. Я решил что `цепная` и `сцена`. Не правда ли умственно? Меняю.

```
пСя ЙеБПЫесцЙенная П несЧСБУЧС пеХБПцеБУная НСсШХПна сразШ наЕраБа НрОцП П
рЙанШБасУ ЙНереХ с ШпСп разрезая ЙСХШ РШБ пцСра ШсПБПБся П зЙШЧ сцаБ ЙОе я
СРБянШБасУ цепная сцена сЧаБ ЕОсцрС ШХаБяБасУ за ЧСраЕБеп цянШБся
НСЕБесЧПЙаЛЭПЬ сереЕрСп сБеХ
```

Первое слово превратилось `пСя`, и я не знаю, как его починить, но конь уже закусил удила. `сразШ` это `сразу`, `наЕраБа` - `набрала`, `уХаляласУ` - `удалялась`.

```
пСя ЙелПЫесцЙенная П несЧСльЧС педлПцельная НСсудПна сразу набрала НрОцП П
рЙанулась ЙНеред с упСп разрезая ЙСду Рул пцСра усПлПлся П зЙуЧ сцал ЙОе я
СРлянулась цепная сцена сЧал бОсцрС удалялась за ЧСраблеп цянулся
НСблесЧПЙаЛЭПЬ серебрСп след
```

Всё больше слов читается: `рЙанулась` - `рванулась`, `вНеред` - `вперед`, `звуЧ` - `звук`. `я СРлянулась` - `я оглянулась`!

```
поя велПЫесцвенная П несколько педлПцельная посудПна сразу набрала прОцП П
рванулась вперед с упоп разрезая воду гул пцора усПлПлся П звук сцал вОе я
оглянулась цепная сцена скал бОсцро удалялась за кораблеп цянулся
поблескПваЛЭПЬ сереброп след
```

`посудПна` это `посудина`. Текст уже читается, хотя и несколько картавый:

```
поя велиЫесцвенная и несколько педлицельная посудина сразу набрала прОци и
рванулась вперед с упоп разрезая воду гул пцора усилился и звук сцал вОе я
оглянулась цепная сцена скал бОсцро удалялась за кораблеп цянулся
поблескиваЛЭиЬ сереброп след
```

`поя` - это ошибка. Должно быть `моя`. Ищу по истории замен, где я ошибся. Обнаруживаю, что `цепная сцена` на деле `цемная сцена`, а это, в свою, очередь `темная стена`! Откатываю изменения, правлю и получаю:

```
моя велиЫественная и несколько медлительная посудина сразу набрала прОти и
рванулась вперед с умом разрезая воду гул мтора усилился и звук стал вОе я
оглянулась темная стена скал бОстро удалялась за кораблем тянулся
поблескиваЛЭиЬ серебром след
```

`велиЫественная` - `величественная`, `бОстро` - `быстро`.

```
моя величественная и несколько медлительная посудина сразу набрала прыти и
рванулась вперед с умом разрезая воду гул мтора усилился и звук стал вые я
оглянулась темная стена скал быстро удалялась за кораблем тянулся
поблескиваЛЭиЬ серебром след
```

Тут я встрял. `мтора` и `вые` это, видимо, обещанные опечатки: `мотора` и `выше`. `с умом` воду не разрезают, её разрезают `с шумом` - ещё одна опечатка. А что такое тогда `поблескиваЛЭиЬ`? Сдаюсь и гуглю. Это `поблескивающий` из "Что сказал покойник" Иоанны Хмелевской.

```
моя величественная и несколько медлительная посудина сразу набрала прыти и
рванулась вперед с умом разрезая воду гул мтора усилился и звук стал вые я
оглянулась темная стена скал быстро удалялась за кораблем тянулся
поблескивающий серебром след
```

О да! Это был отличное расследование и очень в стиле Хмелевской. Спасибо!

Comment: Тайна пляшущих человечков раскрыта глубокой ночью ;)

Comment: а частотный анализ то как-то пригодился? :D

Comment: @teran, нет, не пригодился.

Answer (score 2):

Держите ручной инструмент в помощь :D на полный экран

```js
const txt = 'ЩСЗ ЙАБПЫАИДЙАЮЮВЗ П ЮАИЧСБУЧС ЩАХБПДАБУЮВЗ НСИШХПЮВ ИГВЦШ ЮВЕГВБВ НГОДП П ГЙВЮШБВИУ ЙНАГАХ И ШЩСЩ ГВЦГАЦВЗ ЙСХШ РШБ ЩДСГВ ШИПБПБИЗ П ЦЙШЧ ИДВБ ЙОА З СРБЗЮШБВИУ ДАЩЮВЗ ИДАЮВ ИЧВБ ЕОИДГС ШХВБЗБВИУ ЦВ ЧСГВЕБАЩ ДЗЮШБИЗ НСЕБАИЧПЙВЛЭПЬ ИАГАЕГСЩ ИБАХ';

const alphabet = [{l: "а", v: 3}, {l: "б", v: 21}, {l: "в", v: 9}, {l: "г", v: 19}, {l: "д", v: 13}, {l: "е", v: 2}, {l: "ё", v: 33}, {l: "ж", v: 25}, {l: "з", v: 20}, {l: "и", v: 4}, {l: "й", v: 23}, {l: "к", v: 11}, {l: "л", v: 10}, {l: "м", v: 12}, {l: "н", v: 5},{l: "о", v: 1}, {l: "п", v: 14},{l: "р", v: 8}, {l: "с", v: 7},{l: "т", v: 6}, {l: "у", v: 15},{l: "ф", v: 31},{l: "х", v: 24},{l: "ц", v: 28},{l: "ч", v: 22},{l: "ш", v: 26},{l: "щ", v: 29},{l: "ъ", v: 32},{l: "ы", v: 17},{l: "ь", v: 18},{l: "э", v: 30},{l: "ю", v: 27},{l: "я", v: 16}];

$("#code").text(txt);

alphabet.sort((a,b) => a.v - b.v).forEach(function(item, idx){
  $(`<td>${item.l}</td>`).appendTo("#letters");
  $(`<td>${34-item.v}</td>`).appendTo("#src");
});

let map = txt.split('').reduce(function(acc, v){
    if (v != ' ') {
        acc[v] = (acc[v] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
Object.entries(map)
  .map(entry => ({ l: entry[0], v: entry[1] }))
  .sort((a,b) => b.v-a.v)
  .forEach(function(item){
     $(`<td>${item.l}</td>`).appendTo("#txt");
     $(`<td>${item.v}</td>`).appendTo("#target");
     $(`<td><input class="" style="width:25px"/></td>`).appendTo("#inputs");
  });
  
$("#inputs input").keyup(function(){
  let result = txt;
  $("#letters td").removeClass('active');
  $("input").each(function(idx, el){
     let letter = $("#txt td").eq(idx).text();     
     let v =  $(this).val();
     if (v) {
        result = result.replaceAll(letter, `<mark>${v}</mark>`);
        //console.dir(letter, v);
        $('#letters td').each(function(){               
          if ($(this).text() == v) {
              $(this).addClass('active');
          }
        });
     }
  });
  $("#code").html(result);  
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}

#code {
   font-family: Courier, Consolas;
}
mark {
   padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
  <tr id="letters"></tr>
  <tr id="src"></tr>
    
</table>

<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
  <tr id="txt"></tr>
  <tr id="target"></tr>
  <tr id="inputs"></tr>
</table>
<div id="code" class="px-5"></div>
```

Comment: Отличный инструмент!