# Расшифровать текст методом частотного анализа!

Tags: криптография

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
а йзизшцесз бгдрцр чр шзьйъ, щ ъдрщзж ёзщащо чр ьрщю - тз фрёиюйеа зщйрсрцзщо жечъй шайо, р зкзижейо шзтшещёъ чгзбызтежз ежгччз щгвзтча, ебз шзщцгтчех тгчо. мъжгце жрмечю, ёиеьрце втг-йз чрт чрже сзизчю, шзфтчаа зщгчо шзцесрцр ызцзтчюж жгцёеж тздтгж, чз жчг бюцз дриёз. бющйигг, бющйигг, бющйигг! чъдчз бюцз щтгцрйо яйз гэг сьгир, чз с бебцезйгёъ шиемце чзсюг ёчеве, а фрчежрцрщо игвещйирлегх сгщо тгчо, шзйзж шзйзё мёзцочеёзс чг шзфсзцец зщйрсейо зцгчоёъ зтчъ с ьейрцочзж фрцг, е сзй щгхьрщ щйигжейгцочз бгвъ, щйъьр ёрбцъьёрже шз ефнгтгччзжъ йигэечрже рщкрцойъ, е жзцпщо, ьйзбю сигжа фржгтцецзщо ызйо чгжчзвз. чр шзьйг ирбзйргй щсгйцрчр чеёзцргсчр, жецра е тзбира дгчэечр, ёзйзира ирте жгча фртгидейща чр чгщёзцоёз жечъй, чз йзцоёз бю зчр чг ъмцр.
   тзбгдрцр тз шгигёигщйёр, зщйрчзсецрщо, ёъщра въбю, е зйщьейюсра щгёъчтю чрт ёирщчюж щевчрцзж щсгйзкзир. фгцгчюх! щиюсрпщо чр бгв. бгф йигы жечъй шайо!
   е шзвцатюсра чр ьрщю, а ширёйеьгщёе фрбюцр зб зёиъдрпэеы, зйжгйес бзёзсюж фигчегж виъшшъ жъдьеч с ьгичзж. сшгигте ъдг сетчгцзщо фтрчег шзьйю, е а фрбюцр збз сщгж ёизжг тсгигх с сздтгцгччзг фтрчег, ёрё стиъв чр жзгж шъйе зёрфрцща жъдьечр. ьъсщйсейгцочз ътриесмещо з чгздетрччъп шигвиртъ, йзизшцесз ефсечецрщо е ъдг ызйгцр шизтзцдейо шъйо, чз жгча зщйрчзсеце. чг шзтчежра вцрф, шзшюйрцрщо збзхйе, е ъщцюмрцр ьъйо ыиешцзг:
   - тгсзьёр, чг сейрх с збцрёры.
   сфтизвчъцр е шзтчацр сфвцат чр ефцемчг чрщйюичзвз шигтщйрсейгца жъдщёзвз шцгжгче. чр жгча щжзйигце ьгичюг вцрфр жъдьечю щигтчеы цгй, чр сещёры бцгщйгцр гтср збзфчрьесмраща щгтечр. тзизвра зтгдтр, злгчесрпэех сфвцат, ёигшёег жюмлю шзт щсейгизж - йешеьчюх "ызфаеч дефче".
   - шизщйейг, - йзцоёз щгхьрщ шзчацр, ьйз яйзй жгча гэг е збчежргй, - а зьгчо щшгмъ е...
   сзёиъв мъжгцр дефчо чрмгвз шизсечлерцочзвз, чз жчзвзцптчзвз взизтёр, вътгце жрмечю, тздто щйрчзсецща щецочгг, р жза чгздетрччра шигвиртр мгимрсзх цртзчоп шизсгцр шз эгёг, шрцолрже збиещзсрцр въбю е а ъщцюмрцр гэг бзцгг ыиешцюх сзшизщ:
   - фржъдгж?
   - чччгй, - сзшизщ ътесец е чрщйзиздец.
   - тгйе? - шизтзцдец зч щширмесрйо.
   - чччгйъ... - а ирщйгиаччз ъщйрсецрщо чр чгвз, чг шзчежра, ё ьгжъ сщг яйе сзшизщю. с тъмг фрсзизьрцзщо цувёзг бгщшзёзхщйсз.
   - сзфирщй?
   - тсртлрйо щгжо, - шзщцъмчз зйсгйецр а, ызйа жзвцр ширсгтчз сзфжъйейоща -- ъ дгчэеч чг щширмесрпй, щёзцоёз еж цгй, е йгж бзцгг жъдьечю!
   - чртз дг, - чгфчрёзжгл щйирччз е чгшиеайчз ъцюбчъцща, зёечъс жгча злгчесрпэеж сфвцатзж, - р йрё щирфъ е чг щёрдгмо, трц бю тсртлрйо тср, чг бзцомг.
   ътесцгччз щжзйип чр чгвз е йъй сщшзжечрп - шзьйр!
   - шизщйейг, - игмейгцочз зйщйъшецр, сющсзбзтесмещо еф гвз иъё, гэг ирф сфвцачъцр чр ьрщю, - зх бцеч! ъдг шайо!
   е фрбюс з чгшиеайчзж ирфвзсзиг, а шзбгдрцр, шиетгидесра ёирх шрцойз. втг-йз шзфрте ъщцюмрцр шизефчгщгччзг ызцзтчюж йзчзж "ызьъ", е счгфршчз шизбирцр цгтачра тиздо, чгщжзйиа трдг чр йз, ьйз шзёр бгдрцр ё шзьйг, сщшзйгцр. зйьгвз-йз шзтъжрцзщо, жю гэу сщйигйежща... а игмейгцочз исрчъцр чр щгба тсгио сздтгцуччзвз фрсгтгчеа е йзизшцесз мрвчъцр счъйио.
   сзисрсмещо с фтрчег щзсгйщёзх шзщйизхёе, втг сщг сгацз щзсёзсзх щйриечзх, ъщшгцр ёрё ирф ё жзжгчйъ, ёзвтр щсгйцрчр чеёзцргсчр фрёиюсрцр зёзмгьёз.
   - риемр сеёйзизсчр, зшайо шзтшещёъ с шзщцгтчех тгчо зкзижцагйг?
```

Comment: В чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy необходимо получить исходный текст, который был зашифрован, сделать замену букв

Comment: @Духсообщества [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1527054/Помогите-расшифровать-текст-методом-частотного-анализа]

Comment: Частоты отдельных букв не помогают для коротких текстов. Можно пробовать частоты пар или более длинных последовательностей.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можете помочь?

Comment: Вам нужен конкретный текст или программа для любого текста?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy конкретный текст

Answer (score 2):

**Любовница демона**
*Любовное фэнтези и фантастика*  Кира Александрова

---

```
{'з': 'о', 'р': 'а', 'г': 'е', 'ч': 'н', 'е': 'и', 'й': 'т', 'ц': 'л', 'щ': 'с', 'с': 'в', 'и': 'р', 'т': 'д', 'ж': 'м', 'ш': 'п', 'ъ': 'у', 'ё': 'к', 'а': 'я', 'о': 'ь', 'ю': 'ы', 'ф': 'з', 'б': 'б', 'в': 'г', 'д': 'ж', 'ь': 'ч', 'м': 'ш', 'х': 'й', 'ы': 'х', 'э': 'щ', 'п': 'ю', 'л': 'ц', 'к': 'ф', 'я': 'э'}
```

---

```
я торопливо бежала на почту, с ужасом косясь на часы - до закрытия оставалось минут пять, а оформить подписку необходимо именно сегодня, ибо последний день. шумели машины, кричали где-то над нами вороны, поздняя осень поливала холодным мелким дождем, но мне было жарко. быстрее, быстрее, быстрее! нужно было сделать это еще вчера, но в библиотеку пришли новые книги, я занималась регистрацией весь день, потом поток школьников не позволил оставить оленьку одну в читальном зале, и вот сейчас стремительно бегу, стуча каблучками по изнеденному трещинами асфальту, и молюсь, чтобы время замедлилось хоть немного. на почте работает светлана николаевна, милая и добрая женщина, которая ради меня задержится на несколько минут, но только бы она не ушла.
       добежала до перекрестка, остановилась, кусая губы, и отсчитывая секунды над красным сигналом светофора. зеленый! срываюсь на бег. без трех минут пять!
       и поглядывая на часы, я практически забыла об окружающих, отметив боковым зрением группу мужчин в черном. впереди уже виднелось здание почты, и я забыла обо всем кроме дверей в вожделенное здание, как вдруг на моем пути оказался мужчина. чувствительно ударившись о неожиданную преграду, торопливо извинилась и уже хотела продолжить путь, но меня остановили. не поднимая глаз, попыталась обойти, и услышала чуть хриплое:
       - девочка, не витай в облаках.
       вздрогнула и подняла взгляд на излишне настырного представителя мужского племени. на меня смотрели черные глаза мужчины средних лет, на висках блестела едва обозначившаяся седина. дорогая одежда, оценивающий взгляд, крепкие мышцы под свитером - типичный "хозяин жизни".
       - простите, - только сейчас поняла, что этот меня еще и обнимает, - я очень спешу и...
       вокруг шумела жизнь нашего провинциального, но многолюдного городка, гудели машины, дождь становился сильнее, а моя неожиданная преграда шершавой ладонью провела по щеке, пальцами обрисовала губы и я услышала еще более хриплый вопрос:
       - замужем?
       - нннет, - вопрос удивил и насторожил.
       - дети? - продолжил он спрашивать.
       - нннету... - я растерянно уставилась на него, не понимая, к чему все эти вопросы. в душе заворочалось лугкое беспокойство.
       - возраст?
       - двадцать семь, - послушно ответила я, хотя могла праведно возмутиться -- у женщин не спрашивают, сколько им лет, и тем более мужчины!
       - надо же, - незнакомец странно и неприятно улыбнулся, окинув меня оценивающим взглядом, - а так сразу и не скажешь, дал бы двадцать два, не больше.
       удивленно смотрю на него и тут вспоминаю - почта!
       - простите, - решительно отступила, высвободившись из его рук, еще раз взглянула на часы, - ой блин! уже пять!
       и забыв о неприятном разговоре, я побежала, придерживая край пальто. где-то позади услышала произнесенное холодным тоном "хочу", и внезапно пробрала ледяная дрожь, несмотря даже на то, что пока бежала к почте, вспотела. отчего-то подумалось, мы ещу встретимся... я решительно рванула на себя дверь вожделунного заведения и торопливо шагнула внутрь.
       ворвавшись в здание советской постройки, где все веяло совковой стариной, успела как раз к моменту, когда светлана николаевна закрывала окошечко.
       - ариша викторовна, опять подписку в последний день оформляете?
```

Comment: спасибо огромное